# Convert Hex value "2B" to "+" sign in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, hex, ascii

The ascii value of + sign is 43. The hex value is 2B. I am trying to take the hex value "2B" which is stored as varchar and convert it to a + sign in sql. Any ideas? i cannot seem to find the answer on google and tried different things and cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Assuming this is SQL Server.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), '0x2b', 1))
```